# Can't upload iOS app to the iOS app store

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm having a really difficult time trying to get this app loaded to the iOS App Store. I'm so soured on this idea of keychain's and certificates and provisioning profiles, this might just be my last iOS app. Nevertheless, I would like to try to upload this app to the app store I spent the last 3 months on. Anyways, I have a plethora of problems no matter how I try to attack this.

When I download a certificate from the dev center after creating a developer provisioning profile and doing the whole Request Certificate From a Certificate Authority thing, and try to double click it, nothing happens and it doesn't upload to my KeyChain. Keep in mind that this is the only Apple Computer I've ever used in my life.

When I try to create a Distribution provisioning profile, as per Apple's tutorial, I get *Valid signing identity not found*, in Organizer Provisioning Profiles.

When I try to validate or distribute from Archive in Organizer, it keeps pestering me for a Developer's profile, which I don't have. And Apple's dev center is of zero help when I try searching for this topic.

What am I missing?

Comment: Relax, almost all our first uploads were like yours, AND mine was using the even more "shitty" Xcode 3 :) .. I suggest you follow a tutorial outside apple. Start fresh by revoking your certificate and deleting them from your Mac, and start all over.

Comment: @Mazyod Tried that my man. All of what you suggested. I've deleted everything and reinstalled certs, provisions, signing requests at least 5 times now. And I'm currently looking at my 3rd tutorial right now, which isn't going so great. And let me just say, I do not appreciate the mods deleting my curse words out of my description. I think they really showed the anger and frustration of the whole process, that just doesn't have the same impact without them. We're all adults here, so I don't see the problem. And hopefully if an Apple employee sees this in search, they can somehow streamline it.

Comment: John, [profanity is not allowed on Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites).

Comment: try this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THKpJrMu204) it's a series of 5 videos for submitting apps.  Best tutorial that I've seen

Comment: @user784044 Somebody give this man a round of applause. This is the link that saved me from being committed to a mental institution. It took me several tries even with this tutorial, but it was worth it in the end. Make this an official answer so I can accept it

Comment: If you don't have a developer profile, then you must have missed a step in the docs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THKpJrMu204  it's a series of 5 videos for submitting apps. Best tutorial that I've seen – user784044

Answer (score 1):

Apple has an [Entire Technical Note 2250](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html) related to troubleshooting code signing issues that has always been helpful to me.